# Prevent User from entering values into URL

Tags: php

I have a PHP website based on codeigniter. It uses Mode View Controller and has articles. Each article has id and is displayed by Articles controller. Once an article is displayed the url looks like **http://localhost/ci/articles/show_article/245**. Now the problem is any one can enter number like 246 123 222 and view the articles at random. am not comfortable with this. I want readers to go the way things are organized in the site and want to stop them from directly accessing the articles from URL.
How can this be achieved in PHP / codeigniter.??

Comment: any attempt to control this will end in frustrated users and quite possibly hurt your SEO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't control user outside the browser area, and if you could. you should not.

Alternatively, you could use encoded article Ids by your own pattern to make it unpredictable. when these encoded article ids are  received, decode them back and show the articles accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot ..for your help so what i understood is that it can be done using session_flags AND encrypting the articl ids but may hurt my SEO.. thanks a lot

Comment: @ceemabiswas Will hurt your SEO, not may. You'll be preventing google from crawling your articles at all. And you'll also be confusing your users, preventing others from sharing your links. You'll basically be breaking the web for your site.

Comment: Wouldn't if you follow a strict pattern. SEO Does not care for URL Predictability. all that count is. the Ids should stay same to the whole of article's life cycle.

Comment: @RabNawaz if he enforces article order with Session he will. Because google doesn't just sit there and click links, the links go into a database and are hit in totally unexpected orders, often by totally different machines, and I don't know if it even bothers with cookies (sessions)

Comment: The usage of session is not my recommendation... I suggested a strict pattern.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done. You cannot control what a user types into the web browser.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to do this, and there's also no reason that you *should* be uncomfortable with it.  You can't prevent client-side requests.  I think anyone trying to use your site properly (assuming it is set up properly) won't try to go through articles out of order.

If you absolutely must, what you can do is something like set a `_SESSION` flag for what articles they have visited and if they try to get to one out of order, redirect them.

Comment: Thanks a lot ..for your help so what i understood is that it can be done using session_flags AND encrypting the articl ids but may hurt my SEO.. thanks a lot